# Curb water shut off access pipe too high

Tags: plumbing, water, landscaping, backyard, utilities

After removing a tree, the grade on the front of my property changed, exposing the water cut off access pipe (not sure what it's actually called). How should I go about cutting it down. Is it a DIY project? Or do I have to engage the water company?

[image]

Comment: it is just an empty pipe ... that one looks like it has extension rings ... try unscrewing the sections

Comment: TBH, I doubt that's access to the meter/shutoff. Most meter boxes are rectangular and contain both the meter and a shutoff valve. At least, _I've_ never seen a shutoff like that... The cap obviously says "WATER", what does the rest of it say?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That valve belongs to the water utility and you should not tamper with it.

To get them to address the issue promptly, tell them you fear that it will be damaged/struck by a landscaper during your work and/or that it presents a safety (tripping) hazard. They may need to replace the whole valve, which might require shutting down the water to your street at a main-line valve at the nearest road intersection.

Comment: If the grade change was on his property, the water company could charge him for the work.

Comment: Or put a planter around it...

Comment: JACK and Aloysius Defenestrate both make excellent points! Call the water company - if they'll do it for free, let them deal with it. Otherwise, if the price is unreasonable (and they'll let you leave it alone) hide it with some _moveable_ planters (they're likely going to want clear, easy access to it.